# How not to load the whole document, but line by line - xml, python, using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I used the xml.etree.ElementTree library, 'for' loop and should theoretically read line by line.

Unfortunately, this is probably not, because after executing the script it receives the message 'Killed', so the script does not read line by line. Can anyone help me, suggest something.

Im beginner.

This is my code:

````
from xml.etree import ElementTree

file_name = 'input.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('data', file_name))

dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
root = dom.getroot()

for offer in root.findall('offer'):
    for category in offer.findall('category'):
        if category.text == 'f':
            a = ElementTree.SubElement(offer, 'freedelivery')
            a.text = 'true'
    dom.write(output.xml) ```
````

Comment: Is input.xml a very large file?

Comment: @mzjn yes, 2gb.

Comment: `ElementTree.parse(full_file)` reads the whole file into memory. There are ways to avoid this, for example by using the `iterparse()` method. Start by looking at similar questions about processing large XML files: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+xml+large+file

Answer (score 0):

I have the following remarks concerning your code:

1. `dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)` reads the **whole** input file
   (not line by line).
2. Your 2 nested loops:

   ```
   for offer in root.findall('offer'):
       for category in offer.findall('category'):
   ```

   can be replaced with a **single** loop:

   ```
   for category in root.findall('offer/category'):
   ```
3. Instruction writing the updated *dom* tree should be **outside** the
   first *for* loop (delete its indentation).
4. And the last, probably the basic reason your code failed is that the
   output file name should be **in quotes**, so change it to `dom.write('output.xml')`.
   Otherwise there will be execution error.